# (f) script works (e) doesnt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have these two scripts that do the same thing just on different pages, but the f script works and the e script doesnt, any help??

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "RS3 Points" ||
    e.range.columnStart < 9 || e.range.columnStart > 35 ||
    e.range.rowStart < 4 || e.range
    .columnStart < e.range.columnEnd) return;
e.range.offset(0, 37 - e.range.columnStart).setValue(new Date());
}

function onEdit(f) {
if (f.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "OS Points" ||
    f.range.columnStart < 6 || f.range.columnStart > 37 ||
    f.range.rowStart < 4 || f.range
    .columnStart < f.range.columnEnd) return;
f.range.offset(0, 39 - f.range.columnStart).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: This is a standard Javascript behavior; "[if you define multiple functions with the same name then the last one defined will be the one that actually runs](http://javascript.about.com/library/blpolyfunc.htm)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Munkey's intuition is right. You can't have more than one onEdit() in the same project. Moreover 'e' is not a random letter (that can be replaced by any other letter) but stands for 'event object'. You can read more about that [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). The solution would indeed consist in 'merging' the two scripts into one. Give this a try:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ind = ["RS3 Points", "OS Points"].indexOf(e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName()),
    startCol = [9, 6],
    endCol = [35, 37],
    offset = [37, 39];
if (ind === -1 || e.range.columnStart < startCol[ind] || e.range.columnStart > endCol[ind] ||
    e.range.rowStart < 4 || e.range.columnStart < e.range.columnEnd) return;
e.range.offset(0, offset[ind] - e.range.columnStart)
    .setValue(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have 2 onEdits in google scripts.

If you comment out the `f` function, does the `e` one work?

cant you put them in one onedit function as a solution.

```
    function onEdit(e) {
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "RS3 Points" ||
    e.range.columnStart < 9 || e.range.columnStart > 35 ||
    e.range.rowStart < 4 || e.range
    .columnStart < e.range.columnEnd) return;
e.range.offset(0, 37 - e.range.columnStart).setValue(new Date());



if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "OS Points" ||
    e.range.columnStart < 6 || e.range.columnStart > 37 ||
    e.range.rowStart < 4 || e.range
    .columnStart < e.range.columnEnd) return;
e.range.offset(0, 39 - e.range.columnStart).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Something like that, but its untested.
I think If i'm reading your code correctly, you're looking for Not equals to sheet name, it might be better to change it to equals instead.